# sfdx force:apex:test:report is generating false PassRate as 100% though Failures present in the report

Tags: unit-test, salesforcedx, code-coverage, salesforcedx-cli, failing-tests

I have tried to run the apex tests and generate the test report on source deployed scratchOrg.

report is showing Failure's count as 4 and Outcome as 'Failed' too, still shows the PassRate as 100%.

This is strange.

```
=== Test Summary
NAME                 VALUE
───────────────────  ─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
Outcome              Failed
Tests Ran            2496
Passing              2492
Failing              4
Skipped              0
Pass Rate            100%
Fail Rate            0%
Test Start Time      Oct 7, 2020 9:37 PM
Test Execution Time  7339467 ms
Test Total Time      5169603 ms
Command Time         4115 ms
Hostname             https://saas-innovation-44632-dev-ed.cs10.my.salesforce.com/
Org Id               00DJ0000003Z18pMAC
Username             pr-81-1602103364562@billing.com
Test Run Coverage    61%
Org Wide Coverage    90%
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2492/2496 = 99.84%

It appears that sfdx is simply rounding that number up rather than showing any decimals.

Beyond that, that 61% test run coverage is concerning.

Comment: Salesforce Developer support also mentioned this and, asked to create a idea/Github issue to add more accurate value upto two decimals. I did that too!

Comment: https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0874V0000010y7OQAQ